# Magento session_regenerate_id() error

Tags: magento

I am getting this error in system.log. When this error appears,user can not register.
What can it be? I am using Magento 1.9.3.9

```
2018-08-28T06:42:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed  in D:\workspace\src\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php on line 543
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure apache running at  user, and user has permissions to change files where your local websites are stored else PHP wouldn't start the session.
You need to change the Apache user and everything will be working fine.
Thank you!